# i want to execute a function every time i click on a button Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a dynamic list of colors using jQuery and CSS (and ofc php but this is not related to my issue).

There is a problem when they click on 'choose a color' button my color list will appear and if user click on any of them others will get a display none and here is a problem if user try to change a selected color it doesn't work!

```html
<div class="onfocus">
  <div class="color-select">
    <ul class="ul-color">              
      <li id="slect-color"><a href="#">choose a color</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color5</a></li>                
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.ul-color li').on('click',function(){        
  $(this).css('display','none');

  for(var x = 0 ; x < 10; x++){
    $('.ul-color li').eq(x).css('left', 90*x+'px');
  }

  $('.ul-color li').click(function(){         
    $('.ul-color li').css('display','none');
    $(this).css('display','block');
    $(this).css('left','20px');            
  });
});
```

```css
.onfocus{
    position: absolute;
    left : 50%;
    top :50%;
    width: 1700px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.color-select{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.color-select ul{
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 70px;
    display: flex;  
}
.color-select ul li{
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .5s;  
}
.color-select ul li:nth-child(1){
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.color-select ul li+li{
    left: 20px;
}
.color-select ul li a{
    color : #fff    
}
.color-select ul li:hover{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Before any click :
[pic-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCtpm.jpg)

After i clicked on 'choose a color' :
[pic-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkMD1.png)

if i select any color others will get a display none except the one that we selected and it will get a 'left 20px' too:
[pic-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Umf.png)

so now if i want to change my selected color i have to click on my previous one and it should be something like 2nd picture but nothing gonna happen 
[pic-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yx97.png)

Comment: what is the out put need.?  can you provide a screenshot what you are expecting?

Comment: I edited your question for readability purpose, but I don't understand the second paragraph, and what you're trying to achieve. Please add more details and clearing set what you are expecting.

Comment: @ParTha i added screenshots to my question chek it out .

Comment: @zessx i Appreciate that <3 also added more details please chek it out thanks

Comment: Ok now I understand, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

HTML

```
  <div class="onfocus">
        <div class="color-select">
            <ul class="ul-color">
                <li id="slect-color"><a href="#">choose a color</a></li>
                <li class="color"><a href="#">color1</a></li>
                <li class="color"><a href="#">color2</a></li>
                <li class="color"><a href="#">color3</a></li>
                <li class="color"><a href="#">color4</a></li>
                <li class="color"><a href="#">color5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.ul-color{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
}
.ul-color li{
  margin:5px 10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:#333;
  display:none;
}
.ul-color li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 15px;
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.ul-color li a:hover{
  background:#e74c3c;
}
#slect-color{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#slect-color').on('click',function(){    
  $('ul li').show();
});

$('.color').on('click',function(){   
  $('.color').hide();
  $(this).css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too complex to handle everything with `display: block` and `display: none`. I slightly changed your code to add a few classes:

- `ul.initial` is you initial state, where "Choose a color" is visible
- `ul.opened` is when all colors are shown, for one to be picked
- `li.selected` is the color you've picked

What you want is that any `li` shows up if:

- We're in the initial state, and the `li` is the "Choose a color" one
- We've opened the list, and the `li` is NOT the "Choose a color" one
- The `li` is the one selected

Here's the CSS part that is interesting for you:

```css
.color-select ul.initial #select-color,
.color-select ul.opened li:not(#select-color),
.color-select ul li.selected {
    display: block;
}
```

And below, a working snippet based on your code, with my improvements:

```js
$('.ul-color li').on('click',function() {
  var list = $('.ul-color');
  
  if (!list.hasClass('opened')) {
    // Show all colors
    $('.ul-color li').removeClass('selected');
  } else {
    // A color has been picked
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
  
  list.toggleClass('opened');
  list.removeClass('initial');
});
```

```css
.onfocus{
    /* Be careful, this part one changed only to be visible in the snippet */
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}
.color-select {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.color-select ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;  
}
.color-select ul li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px; 
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.color-select ul.initial #select-color,
.color-select ul.opened li:not(#select-color),
.color-select ul li.selected {
    display: block;
}
.color-select ul li a {
    color : #fff    
}
.color-select ul li:hover{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="onfocus">
  <div class="color-select">
    <ul class="ul-color initial">              
      <li id="select-color"><a href="#">choose a color</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">color5</a></li>                
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```